# Troubleshooting with a .NET application that doesn't start C# VS2015

Tags: c#, .net

I have a problem with a aplication I have created with vidual; studio 2015 C#.
The setup.exe runs good on the machine I have created it on, but when I run the setup.exe on a different machine the setup runs, but the program doesnt run, no error, it just dont starts.
This is my eventvwr :

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Application Error
Date:          2/7/2016 1:51:40 PM
Event ID:      1000
Task Category: (100)
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      Curry-PC
Description:
Faulting application name: Lensman.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x568fc6e1
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.19110, time stamp: 0x56842600
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x0000c42d
Faulting process id: 0xfcc
Faulting application start time: 0x01d161a648fd5f48
Faulting application path: C:\Users\Curry\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\03HX5VH8.JY1\PRGZ36AK.2LW\lens..tion_0000000000000000_0001.0000_dc52d8a467c6c930\Lensman.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 87911da8-cd99-11e5-a748-001d72a367e8
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Application Error" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>100</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-02-07T12:51:40.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>1072</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>Curry-PC</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>Lensman.exe</Data>
    <Data>1.0.0.0</Data>
    <Data>568fc6e1</Data>
    <Data>KERNELBASE.dll</Data>
    <Data>6.1.7601.19110</Data>
    <Data>56842600</Data>
    <Data>e0434352</Data>
    <Data>0000c42d</Data>
    <Data>fcc</Data>
    <Data>01d161a648fd5f48</Data>
    <Data>C:\Users\Curry\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\03HX5VH8.JY1\PRGZ36AK.2LW\lens..tion_0000000000000000_0001.0000_dc52d8a467c6c930\Lensman.exe</Data>
    <Data>C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll</Data>
    <Data>87911da8-cd99-11e5-a748-001d72a367e8</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

edit: I already try to switch users, but that didnt help.

Comment: The event viewer doesn't give you enough information to diagnose the problem. The exception code (`0xe0434352`) indicates a low-level (albeit generic) problem in the CLR. The best solution would be to attach a debugger to the system. If you can't do that, add a handler for `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` and log detailed information about the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it might be a corrupted user profile.  Try logging in as a different user on the machine (or create a new profile) and see if it works.  Here's a link with another work-around for a similar issue:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/programs-crash-error-fault-module-kernelbasedll/9fe5d2e7-79d0-42c1-b8dc-51ed8d70f749?auth=1

Comment: No that didnt help, I still get the same error.

Comment: Assuming it is a WinForm or WPF application?  What .NET version is it compiled to?  Is it performing much in the way of threading?  You might need to handle some uncaught exceptions, similar to the following thread:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23292547/kernelbase-dll-exception-0xe0434352-offset-0x000000000000a49d

Comment: I added both solutions to the code, but it didnt work. It performs much trheading, but not at startup. And the app doesnt startup.

Comment: Oh, and my .net version is 4.6 :-)