# SSMS 2016 crashes in Edit Top X Rows for Windows 10

Tags: sql-server, windows, windows-10, ssms, sql-server-2016

I'm having a problem where SSMS will crash while trying to scroll through the results of the "Edit Top X Rows".  I have tried reducing the number of rows returned, installing older versions of SSMS, and making sure I am on the latest versions.  I will include the event log, as well as the version information for SSMS.

OS is Windows 10 x64

SSMS Info:
download location: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - 13.0.16000.28
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools - 13.0.1700.441
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) - 10.0.14393.0
Microsoft MSXML - 3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer - 9.11.14393.0
Microsoft .NET Framework - 4.0.30319.42000
Operating System - 6.3.14393
```

Event Log 1

```
Faulting application name: Ssms.exe, version: 2015.130.16000.28, time stamp: 0x580af2c5
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.14393.321, time stamp: 0x57f4c291
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x000da6f2
Faulting process id: 0x3364
Faulting application start time: 0x01d24a529cd4afa4
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: c6e3afb2-b3d0-4857-8eb6-e538c1b22ff2
```

Event Log 2

```
Application: Ssms.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.ArgumentException
   at System.Buffer.BlockCopy(System.Array, Int32, System.Array, Int32, Int32)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DataTools.UI.QueryResult.FileStreamReader.ReadArray[[System.Char, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](Int64, Boolean, Int32, Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DataTools.UI.QueryResult.SpecialDataType ByRef, Char[] ByRef, Int32 ByRef)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DataTools.UI.QueryResult.FileStreamReader.ReadString(Int64, Boolean, Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DataTools.UI.QueryResult.SpecialDataType ByRef, System.String ByRef)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DataTools.UI.QueryResult.DiskStorageView.SequentialReadColumn(Int32, Boolean)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DataTools.UI.QueryResult.DiskStorageView.GetCellDataFromFileInternal(Int64, Int32, Boolean)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DataTools.UI.QueryResult.DiskStorageView.GetCellData(Int64, Int32)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DataTools.UI.QueryResult.StorageViewBase.GetCellDataAsStringInternal(Int64, Int32)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DataTools.UI.QueryResult.DiskStorageView.GetCellDataAsString(Int64, Int32)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DataTools.UI.QueryResult.ResultBindingList.GetValue(Int32, Int32)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DataTools.UI.QueryResult.QueryResultControl.DataGridView_CellValueNeeded(System.Object, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellValueEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCellValueNeeded(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellValueEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCellValueNeeded(Int32, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.GetValue(Int32)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxCell.GetPreferredSize(System.Drawing.Graphics, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle, Int32, System.Drawing.Size)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.GetPreferredWidth(Int32, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.OnCellDataAreaMouseEnterInternal(Int32)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.OnMouseMoveInternal(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnCellMouseMove(System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.UpdateMouseEnteredCell(HitTestInfo, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnMouseMove(System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseMove(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DataTools.UI.QueryResult.DTDataGridView.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
```

Comment: As per this answer,you can configure DrWatson logs if you can reproduce the problem everytime:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23292547/kernelbase-dll-exception-0xe0434352-offset-0x000000000000a49d