# Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll

Tags: c#, dll

My application crashes without any application error logging, when I checked Event viewer I found below info. Can some explain **why this would happen** and **how to prevent** it?

> Faulting application name: MyApplication.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time
>   stamp: 0x5964fac7
>  Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version:
>   6.1.7601.23807, time stamp: 0x5915f98e
>  Exception code: 0xe0434352
>  Fault offset: 0x0000c54f
>  Faulting process id:
>   0x1494
>  Faulting application start time: 0x01d300cbc9034bc0
>   Faulting application path: Path of MyApplication.exe
>  Faulting
>   module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
>  Report Id:
>   b1f21346-6cbf-11e7-bb68-005056ad2203

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/23293119/368552, basically you have an exception in your code (MyApplicaiton.exe) you are not catching, throw a try catch over in the app to see what it is.

Comment: I'm pretty sure my app catches every exception throws.

Comment: @rANth is everything inside your main() method contained in a try catch that logs the exception?  How about all your thread starter methods?

Comment: Try what the answer I linked to you said: There should be a minidump of the crash in DrWatson folders with a full stack, it will contain everything you need to root cause the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [KERNELBASE.dll Exception 0xe0434352 offset 0x000000000000a49d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23292547/kernelbase-dll-exception-0xe0434352-offset-0x000000000000a49d)

Comment: try catch around app won't work for this. you need to add a handler for `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`

Comment: did you use linq to sql ?

Answer (score 1):

I was building a WPF application in C# and packaging it using the MSIX packager/installer.  Everything was fine until I updated Visual Studio to 16.10.2. Then something strange started to happen. The code would run perfectly in Debug and Release configuration but when I installed the application from MSIX it failed to run.

There were no coding errors.

The Event Log gave this error..

Faulting application name: [app name here], version: [app version here], time stamp: 0x609308e7

Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.19041.1023, time stamp: 0x924f9cdb
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x0000000000034b89
Faulting process ID: 0xf3c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d7659e116b2c8c

I tried almost everything but nothing seem to fix it. Then I noticed the the 'obj' folder had become huge, so I deleted it and low and behold that fixed the problem.

Comment: I had this exact problem with Visual Studio 2022 but the solutions did the trick, tnx!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but thought I'd post Luke's advice as an answer since it solved my problem.

As Luke mentioned in a comment above, the issue for me was an unhandled exception that was happening on startup. Once I wrapped the startup code in a try catch, I found the problem which was totally a bug in my app, nothing to do with kernalbase.dll or any other external dependency or reference.

Answer (score 0):

Change the NET Framework setting at least to version 4.6.

With 4.5 I have the same problem, after update to 4.6 the problem solved.